# WebApp in AppServices vs CloudService

Tags: azure-web-roles, azure-cloud-services, azure-web-app-service

Is WebApp (formerly Azure Website) in the newly announced "Azure AppService" the preferred approach to building highly scalable web applications as opposed to using "Azure CloudServices"?

My original understanding was that web applications hosted as "Azure CloudServices" would scale better and "Azure Websites" were for simpler web sites/applications.

I'm building a web application and scalability is a big concern. Which is the "better" approach?

Answer (score 4):

Your exact answer might depend on what you mean by "scale better", but in general WebApps are now pretty much on parity with Cloud Services. See http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/choose-web-site-cloud-service-vm/

To seriously scale you need to keep functionality minimal in the web application and delegate to external resources for computation, messaging and storage. That means the better web technology is the one that can communicate better with outside resources, and the App Service architecture clearly gives that advantage to WebApps.

The App Service preview is just the latest indication that Microsoft intends to continue investing in and promoting WebApps predominately. So unless there's a compelling need for a Cloud Service feature, I would choose WebApps.

Comment: Thank you Richard. I appreciate your answer.