# Azure RoleEnvironment.Changing event not being called in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure

I am trying to use the Azure [Runtime Reconfiguration Pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dn589785.aspx) to allow me to change a appSetting in the normal Web.config file via PowerShell (later by  Microsoft Azure Web Sites Management Library).

My problem is that the [RoleEnvironment.Changing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.windowsazure.serviceruntime.roleenvironment.changing.aspx) event is not being called in my MVC app, so the web app is being restarted. I have placed event set up code in the MVC Application_Start as described in the Azure article, i.e.

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    RoleEnvironment.Changing += RoleEnvironment_Changing;
    RoleEnvironment.Changed += RoleEnvironment_Changed;

    //normal MVC code etc...
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
}
```

The event handlers are a straight copy of the handled from the Azure article and  look like this:

```
    private const string CustomSettingName = "TestConfig";

    public static string TestConfigValue;

    private static void RoleEnvironment_Changing(object sender,
                           RoleEnvironmentChangingEventArgs e)
    {
        RoleLogs.Add("RoleEnvironment_Changing: started");

        var changedSettings = e.Changes.OfType<RoleEnvironmentConfigurationSettingChange>()
                                       .Select(c => c.ConfigurationSettingName).ToList();
        Trace.TraceInformation("Changing notification. Settings being changed: "
                               + string.Join(", ", changedSettings));

        if (changedSettings
          .Any(settingName => !string.Equals(settingName, CustomSettingName,
                                     StringComparison.Ordinal)))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Cancelling dynamic configuration change (restarting).");
            RoleLogs.Add("RoleEnvironment_Changing: restarting!");
            // Setting this to true will restart the role gracefully. If Cancel is not 
            // set to true, and the change is not handled by the application, the 
            // application will not use the new value until it is restarted (either 
            // manually or for some other reason).
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
        else
        {
            RoleLogs.Add("RoleEnvironment_Changing: change is OK. Not restarting");
            Console.WriteLine("Handling configuration change without restarting. ");
        }
    }


    private static void RoleEnvironment_Changed(object sender,
                           RoleEnvironmentChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        RoleLogs.Add("RoleEnvironment_ChangED: Starting");
        Console.WriteLine("Updating instance with new configuration settings.");

        foreach (var settingChange in
                 e.Changes.OfType<RoleEnvironmentConfigurationSettingChange>())
        {
            if (string.Equals(settingChange.ConfigurationSettingName,
                              CustomSettingName,
                              StringComparison.Ordinal))
            {
                // Execute a function to update the configuration of the component.
                RoleLogs.Add("RoleEnvironment_ChangED: TestConfig has changed");
                Console.WriteLine("TestConfig has changed.");
                TestConfigValue = RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue(CustomSettingName);
            }
        }
    }
```

I have added logs which prove that my `RoleEnvironment_Changing` and `RoleEnvironment_Changed` are not being called in the MVC WebApp which means the WebApp is restarted when I change an appSetting via PowerShell. This also means the `RoleEnvironment.Changing` event never gets to the WebJob.

I am using Azure SDK 2.7.0

Any ideas?

## UPDATE

@richag gave me an answer, which made me realise that my problem is because I am using a App Service rather than a Cloud Service. This [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29261963/1434764) and plus this [video](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-Azure-Cloud-Services-Tutorials/Introduction-to-Windows-Azure-Cloud-Services) (see at 5:00mins) talks about the difference (Note: the video is old so the name of the web app is different, but the concept is the same).

I don't really want to change this late in the development, and I have worked round the problem another way. Maybe on the next project and will look at Cloud Services as I can see some positives, like better control of my WebJobs configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the runtime reconfiguration pattern: "Microsoft Azure Cloud Services roles detect and expose two events that are raised when the hosting environment detects a change to the ServiceConfiguration.cscfg files" These events are not fired if you make changes to app.config/web.config files. Only when the cloud service configuration is changed, i.e. if you upload a new configuration file through the azure portal's configure tab or change a setting directly on the azure portal.

Comment: Hi @richag. Your reply made me do some more research. I now realise that I am using a App Service rather than a Cloud Service, which means that the Runtime Reconfiguration won't work. This [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29261963/1434764) and plus this [video](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-Azure-Cloud-Services-Tutorials/Introduction-to-Windows-Azure-Cloud-Services) (see at 5:00mins) talks about it. At this stage I think I will keep to using a Web App and forgo the features of Runtime Reconfiguration.

Answer (score 1):

According to the debugger, none of the following events are fired when I update the Azure Portal to change an AppSetting for an ASP.NET WebAPI app:

```
RoleEnvironment.Changing
RoleEnvironment.Changed
RoleEnvironment.StatusCheck
RoleEnvironment.SimultaneousChanging
RoleEnvironment.SimultaneousChanged
RoleEnvironment.Stopping
```

Do others have different experience?